# How to hide "Super Users" from Users Manager list in the Joomla backend?

Tags: super-user

How can i hide "Super Users" from Users Manager list in the Joomla backend from other user groups?

I have allowed my "Editors" to access a limited version of the Joomla backend. But they can still see me (Super User) listed in the User Manager. They cannot edit my profile, which is good, but how can I hide the Super User row itself from other user groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can only be done using a core modification. Open the file `administrator/components/com_users/views/users/tmpl/default.php` and, just above the line

```
$canEdit   = false;
```

Add the following line:

```
continue;
```

This will prevent super users from being displayed to anyone who is a non super user.

Comment: +1 but would recommend a Template Override instead.